# Plant vs animal protein digestibility?

Tags: proteins, human-physiology, nutrition, amino-acids, digestion

The protein scoring methodologies ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_Digestibility_Corrected_Amino_Acid_Score) rate plant proteins of a lower quality than animal proteins. Now I can understand the reasoning that proteins have a lesser quantity of essential amino acids (allegedly) making them "lower quality" in terms of protein; but I don't see why there should be a difference in *digestibility* between plant and animal proteins (I can give links but it's common knowledge that plant proteins are less digestible). What is the basis for this difference in digestibility ? Whatever the amino acid composition, I don't see how that would affect digestion of proteins. So why are plant proteins considered less digestible ?

Comment: Anti-nutritional factors or antinutrients (wikipedia has a page about this) https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/agricultural-and-biological-sciences/anti-nutritional-factor